# Elementary Basis Transformations to bases of modules

Tags: ring-theory, vector-spaces, modules, change-of-basis

sorry if this is a really obvious question but I am a first year and trying to get my head around the idea of "elementary basis transformations" to bases of finite dimensional vector spaces over a field (or more generally, finitely generated modules over a ring). From what I gather, this includes:

$\bullet$ Adding one basis element (or multiples of it) to another basis element. So if $\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots b_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ over a field $F$, then $\{b_1+b_2, b_2,\ldots,b_n\}$ is a basis of $V$. As $\{b_1+b_2,b_2,b_1+b_2+b_3,\ldots,b_n\}$ etc.

$\bullet$ Multiplying a basis element by a non-zero element of $F$. So, $\{ab_1,b_2,\ldots, b_n\}$ is a basis of $V$ if $a\neq 0$.

Is this right? And if so, can we generalise this to free modules over a ring $R$ (any ring, even noncommutative?). I suppose we need to replace $a\neq 0$ to $a$ being a unit in the ring, but is that all we need to change? What about replacing $b_1$ by $b_1+2b_2$ in the basis. Does it matter if 2 is not a unit in the ring, e.g. $R=\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Welcome to Maths SX! It won't be a problem since the reverse transformation has the same type. And yes, the only thing to change is that  only scalar multiplication by a unit is  allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @Bernard! So by the reverse transformation you mean subtracting basis elements? I only ask because I know a change of basis is effected by an invertible matrix $P$ s.t. $P^{-1}BP=B^\prime$ (say). So $P=T_1\cdots T_N$ where each $T_i$ is a matrix with 1s on the diagonal and one off-diagonal element coding for adding a basis element. $P^{-1}$ will just be the inverse of this (so we subtract basis elements). Is this right?

Comment: Perfectly right. Each elementary operation on the rows of a matrix can be seen as pre-multiplying by an  elementary operation matrix, and similarly, operations on columns consists in post-multiplying  by elementary operation matrices.

Comment: @Bernard Great, thank you so much